# What is the C# equivalent to Get-AzureRmSqlServerThreatDetectionPolicy?

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sql-server

So the [docs for this cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/get-azurermsqlserverthreatdetectionpolicy?view=azurermps-6.11.0) show some very interesting information I would like to programmatically read in C#. The `SqlManagementClient` does not seem to directly expose the threat detection policy of the server. I can get the database threat detection policies in `DatabaseThreatDetectionPolicies`, but I want the server policy.

Can anyone point me to documentation on how to get that information in C#?

Comment: This issue is still relevant to this day, I could not easily find the Java methods for a lot of the command lines. Do you found the solution for this in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this appears to be a poor nomenclature issue. It seems the `ServerSecurityAlertPolicies` represent the `ThreatDetectionPolicies` at the server level. This was confusing, as it has different naming for the same info at the server and DB level.

For clarity for anyone who searches for this in the future (and please correct me if my hypothesis is wrong), it appears that:

- Audit logging at the server level is held in `ServerBlobAuditingPolicies`
- Threat Detection logging at the server level is held in `ServerSecurityAlertPolicies`
- Audit logging at the database level is held in `DatabaseBlobAuditingPolicies`
- Threat Detection logging at the server level is held in `DatabaseThreatDetectionPolicies`

HTH anyone following this trail later.